# How to modify anchor's behavior (href/onclick()) after page that uses Vue has been rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js

## TL;DR

I need to change the URL of an anchor. The anchor has the `__vue__` property. Simply modifying the `href` attribute of the anchor is not changing the behavior when clicking on it. Using vanilla Javascript, how can I change the anchor in Vue so that the anchor points to where I need it to point? (I only have access to the DOM since this is a 3rd party CMS that I can't control).

## More details

I'm using a CMS service that allows to load custom Javascript in the `<head>` section of page.

The rendered website has multiple anchors pointing to different URLs each.

I want to change the URL for one of the elements.

I've tried doing:

```
els = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/here"]');
els.forEach((el) => {
  el.href="/elsewhere"; 
  el.onClick = (e) => {e.preventDefault()}
})
```

**The problem** is that clicking on the anchor element it still goes `/here` instead of `/elsewhere` as expected.

Upon further review, the anchor elements have the `__vue__` property, suggesting these were created and are managed by Vue.js.

How can I use vanilla Javascript to modify the `href` of these anchors and update Vue.js on where the link is pointing ?

For what its worth, here's a screenshot of `<a/>` tag I see in the browser whose `href` I want to modify:

[image]

Comment: Is this element part of a Vue template?  It would be best to show the html / script

Comment: yes, it has an `element.__vue__` property, if that's what your asking... updated the question with an image.

Comment: I don't have access to the template, only to the DOM. I'd like to use Javascript to change the link of element and point it elsewhere.

Comment: @tao that sounds like what I want to do. How can I get the Vue instance to modify its data? Thanks

Comment: Is it an external link or a `<router-link>`?

Comment: when inspecting the DOM I just see a normal `<a href="/here'>xxx</a>` tag (which I want to change to point to `/elsewhere`)

Comment: (I just updated the question with an image)

Comment: What you did should work at least temporarily, until the next rerender.  Are you able to inspect and see the href change, even briefly?

Comment: I would say it's an external link. It's an <a> pointing to an href. Though to the same domain, so it just list the path: `/here`. When I change the href to `/elsewhere` and I click on the link it still goes `/here` instead of `/elsewhere` (that is, the link does not go where the href says).